# Get Twitter Profile Pic iPhone iOS5

Tags: iphone, twitter, camera, uiimage

I need help getting the twitter profile pic once I've been granted access to the Twitter account. The code below gets me the profile handle (@twitter). Is there a way to pull this info directly from Twitter in iOS5?

Here's what I have that works for the handle:

```
-(void)getTwitterName
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 

     {
         if(granted) {
             NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from this URL: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/:screen_name.format

My profile image, for example, would be http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/don_kim

You can read more on it [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/%3ascreen_name).

Comment: The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active.